SQL aggregation with condition
Which way is better between:
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN val ELSE 0 END) OVER() c

compare to
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN COUT(*) OVER() ELSE 0 END c


How do you define "better" here? The expressions do different things, so why would you call one "better" than the other?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using.

It depends what you want to do.
Without any grouping/partitioning there are some issues that could affect the result. Look at the simple example below: (comments in code)
WITH    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ID, VAL) AS
        ( Select 1, 1 From Dual Union All 
          Select 2, Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 3, Null From Dual Union All 
          Select 4, 1 From Dual 
        )

1.
-- your code with ELSE 0
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN val ELSE 0 END) OVER() c FROM tbl 
/*   Else 0  -- the zero value is counted
         C
----------
         4
         4
         4
         4  */

--  same code without ELSE (returns Null)
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN val END) OVER() c FROM tbl  
/*     without ELSE 0  -- Null value NOT counted
         C
----------
         2
         2
         2
         2  */

2.
--  with ELSE 0
SELECT CASE WHEN VAL IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) OVER() ELSE 0 END c From   tbl
/*
         C
----------
         4    -- if val exists counts all rows
         0    -- returns 0 from Else - not counting at all
         0    -- returns 0 from Else - not counting at all
         4    -- if val exists counts all rows              */

--  Without ELSE
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) OVER() END c From tbl
/*
         C
----------
         4   -- if val exists counts all rows
             -- returns Null without Else - not counting at all
             -- returns Null without Else - not counting at all
         4   -- if val exists counts all rows                   */


The expressions are very different.
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN val ELSE 0 END) OVER()

This gets you the same count in every result row. Namely the same as COUNT(*) OVER (), because your case expresssion is never null.
Maybe you mean this instead:
SELECT COUNT(val) OVER()

which gives you again the same value in every result row, but this time it is the number of rows having a value.
Or this:
SELECT SUM(val) OVER()

which gives you the sum of all values instead, which again is the same in every result row.
This
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) OVER() ELSE 0 END

on the other hand gives you null in every row where val is null and the number of all rows in the rows that have a val.

Thanks, for suggestion. The syntax is come from the python
https://pypi.org/project/pysqldf/
SELECT CASE WHEN val IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(*) OVER() ELSE 0 END
It can provide the output on my test (not this statement but same context).
